# Proxmox VE - problems in setting private network

Tags: networking, virtualization, proxmox, private-ip

I have recently bought a test dedicated server from to test proxmox. The installation went smoothly; however, I get stuck in the network configurations.

My Use case-

I want to create 8 LXC containers and run our 6 microservices, Nginx and Mysql server on them. I want to get internet traffic to nginx server and rest it should connect over private network. So I need to create a private network and is where I am stuck. And to inform that I not networking expert, just know basics whom tutorial always helped, but not this time.
I have done changes in /etc/network/interfaces, as per the section ‘Masquerading (NAT) with iptables’ of proxmox wiki’s [Networking Configurations article](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration)

This is the configuration in my /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto enp41s0
iface enp41s0 inet static
        address 65.XXX.YYY.181/26
        gateway 65.XXX.YYY.129
        up route add -net 65.XXX.YYY.128 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 65.XXX.YYY.129 dev enp41s0
# route 65.XXX.YYY.128/26 via 65.XXX.YYY.129

iface vmbr0 inet static
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        address 10.10.10.1/24
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/26' -o enp41s0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/26' -o enp41s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Restarting networking after these changes does not throw any errors.

This is the error in proxmox admin panel, when I try to start the newly created LXC container

```
run_buffer: 314 Script exited with status 25
lxc_create_network_priv: 3068 No such device - Failed to create network device
lxc_spawn: 1786 Failed to create the network
__lxc_start: 1999 Failed to spawn container "101"
TASK ERROR: startup for container '101' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a private network and have it NAT to the public interface, add the following configurations to the /etc/network/interfaces (keep the backup of original)

Updated the network bridge vmbr0 and allowed it to use internet traffic Created new network bridge vmbr1 and used for internal networking between containers

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback
auto enp41s0
iface enp41s0 inet manual (prev value static)

Commented this line
#       up route add -net 65.XXX.XXX.128 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 65.XXX.XXX.129 dev enp41s0
```

Bridge that handles internet traffic

```
iface vmbr0 inet static
address 65.XXX.XXX.181/26
gateway 65.XXX.XXX.129
bridge-ports enp41s0
bridge-stp off
bridge-fd 0
```

Bridge that is used by the internal running services

```
auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
address 10.10.10.1/24
bridge-ports none
bridge-stp off
bridge-fd 0
#Bridge network to NAT to vmbr1, uses 10.10.10.0/24 network
#
post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And thankfully I am able to use all microservices , efficiently.

Hope this helps to someone